# Let $M=\left ( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{matrix} \right) $ . Find $M^{2^k}$,where $k \ge 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $M=\left ( \begin{matrix}
> 1 & 1 \\
> 1 & 0 \\
> \end{matrix} \right) $ . Find $M^{2^k}$,where $k \ge 1$.

I found the determinant to be $1$. And I don't know how to proceed from there. I also tried the Cayley-Hamilton theorem but it failed to do anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The determinant of $M$ is $-1$, therefore the determinant of $M^{2^k}$ is $1$. Compute a few $M^k$ for small $k$, and you should see something.

Comment: By the spectral theorem, $M = P^{-1} D P$ for some $D$ diagonal and $P$ invertible. Thus $M^2 = P^{-1} D^2 P $ etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that, in general:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}
F_{n+1} & F_n\\
F_n & F_{n-1} \\
\end{pmatrix},$$

which can be easily obtained by induction and the definition of [the Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).